# Check if a survey got deleted on survey monkey using their API

Tags: surveymonkey

I have an application that pulls daily data from survey monkey using their API. I am looking for a way to check if a survey got deleted on survey monkey.

As far as I know I can send a request on /surveys/{id} and if I get an 404 error (the resource does not exist) it means that the survey is deleted.
The problem is that I checked their [API documentation](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#data-types) and it is stated there that 404 means:

> There was an error retrieving the requested resource

So this error will be send when there is an error retrieving the survey (it does not mean that the survey is deleted).
So, is there a better way to check if a survey got deleted on survey monkey ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way I'm aware of to know that a survey was specifically deleted.

An HTTP 404 response basically means that the survey could not be found. It may be because it got deleted or because it never existed. Unless you need to know specifically it got deleted you can just use the 404 response to determine that you shouldn't be working with that survey.

Note for the future, there is no survey webhook events in the API now but that should be coming at some point. When that happens you'll be able to [subscribe to a webhook](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#webhooks) and perform some action on your side to mark the survey as deleted.